# Fluent NHibernate in msbuild

Tags: nhibernate, msbuild, fluent-nhibernate, build-automation

I'm writing an automated build script to run acceptance tests. My application uses Fluent NHibernate. My build script should deploy the database before running the tests. Is there an msbuild task for creating the database from fluent mappings?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a testbaseclass which creates the database and sessionfactory for all tests once in the static constructor. Its always easier in code.